# htaccess rules to nginx rules

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I need help with reqrite htaccess rules to NGINX rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

if any one could help me if those rules can be worked as NGINX rules

Comment: Are there other rewrite rules exists in your .htaccess after these? Where are request should go if the requested PHP script is absent? To 404 error or to some main handler like `/index.php`?

Comment: no there is no other rules exist its just those rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /$uri.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

You will need the PHP scripts handler `location` block!

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # fastcgi or other backend configuration here
        ...
    }
```

Comment: @AhmedT Do you have `index` directive in your nginx config? Maybe you should try `index index.php index.html index.htm;`.

Comment: Hello Ivan , I have contact with script provider and he give me the original htaccess as he mentioned

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
 RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>